# Variable might not have been initialized using input data

Tags: java, variables, initialization

```
public class Activity2PayStub
{
    public static final double OVERTIME_RATE = 1.5;
    public static final double SS_WITHHOLDING = .1;
    public static final double FEDERAL_TAX = .2;

    private String name;
    private String ssn;
    private int regHours;
    private int overHours;
    private double hourlyRate;

    private double regPay = regHours * hourlyRate;
    private double overRate = hourlyRate * OVERTIME_RATE;
    private double overPay = overHours * OVERTIME_RATE * hourlyRate;
    private double grossPay = regPay + overPay;
    private double ssWith = grossPay * SS_WITHHOLDING;
    private double fedTax = (grossPay - ssWith) * FEDERAL_TAX;
    private double netPay = grossPay - ssWith - fedTax;

    /**
     * It all starts with the main method.
     * 
     * @param args command-line arguments (not used)
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Create an Activity2Paystub object
        //a2ps is an Activity2PayStub object
        Activity2PayStub a2ps = new Activity2PayStub();
        //call the methods inside of an Activity2PayStub object
        a2ps.getInput(keyboard);
        a2ps.calculate();
        a2ps.printPayStub();
    }

    public void getInput(Scanner keyboard) 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter employee name: ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter employee SSN (incl. hyphens): ");
        ssn = keyboard.nextLine();

        int regHours;
        System.out.print("Enter number of regular hours worked: ");
        regHours = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of overtime hours worked: ");
        overHours = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter hourly pay rate: ");
        hourlyRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    public void calculate()
    {
        int regHours;
        int overHours;   
        double hourlyRate; 
        double regPay = regHours * hourlyRate;
        double overRate = hourlyRate * OVERTIME_RATE;
        double overPay = overHours * OVERTIME_RATE * hourlyRate;
        double grossPay = regPay + overPay;
        double ssWith = grossPay * SS_WITHHOLDING;
        double fedTax = (grossPay - ssWith) * FEDERAL_TAX;
        double netPay = grossPay - ssWith - fedTax;
    }
```

I am having problems at:
double regPay = regHours * hourlyRate;
double overPay = overHours * OVERTIME_RATE * hourlyRate;

The problem I am getting is regHours, hourlyRate, and overHours might not have been initialized.

I am trying to get user input, so how would I go by initializing them.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson when I do this I get results of 0.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, you're a life saver! Is there anyway I could mark your work as the correct response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Initialize all necessary values, or move code to run later

Your code such as:

```java
    private double regPay = regHours * hourlyRate;
    private double overRate = hourlyRate * OVERTIME_RATE;
    private double overPay = overHours * OVERTIME_RATE * hourlyRate;
```

… assigns a value by executing code on the right side of the assignment `=`. That code runs when instantiating an object of this class. So when that first example line above runs, it is trying to use `regHours` and `hourlyRate`. But those **member fields have not yet been assigned** a value.

```java
    private int regHours;
    private int overHours;
    private double hourlyRate;
```

So you need to understand the lifecycle of a class.

- When the class is first loaded by the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) [class loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader), your `static` variables/constants are established.
- When instantiating an object of this class via `new`, those declaration lines run first, then the constructor.
- Then your methods run when called.

If you cannot initialize a value for all required variables at the point of their declaration, then move your calculation code to a constructor.

If you cannot know an initial value at the point of construction, move your code to some method that can be called at the appropriate time.

### Example code

Here is somewhat cleaned-up version of your code. This is quick-and-dirty. I have not verified your logic, nor have I done any testing.

```java
package work.basil.example.paystub;

import java.util.Objects;

public class PayStub
{
    public static final double OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER = 1.5, WITHHOLDING_MULTIPLIER = .1, FEDERAL_TAX = .2;

    // inputs
    private String name, employeeId;
    private int regHours, overHours;
    private double hourlyRate;

    // results
    // In real work, we would be using `BigDecimal` or integers for money, never `double`/`float`.
    private double overRate, regPay, overPay, grossPay, withholdingAmount, fedTax, netPay;

    public PayStub ( String name , String employeeId , int regHours , int overHours , double hourlyRate )
    {
        // In real work, we would do more data-validation. For example, checking for minimum, maximum, or unreasonable values.
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull( name );
        this.employeeId = Objects.requireNonNull( employeeId );
        this.regHours = Objects.requireNonNull( regHours );
        this.overHours = Objects.requireNonNull( overHours );
        this.hourlyRate = Objects.requireNonNull( hourlyRate );

        this.calculate();
    }

    public void calculate ( )
    {
        this.regPay = regHours * hourlyRate;
        this.overRate = hourlyRate * OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER;
        this.overPay = overHours * hourlyRate;
        this.grossPay = regPay + overPay;
        this.withholdingAmount = grossPay * WITHHOLDING_MULTIPLIER;
        this.fedTax = ( grossPay - withholdingAmount ) * FEDERAL_TAX;
        this.netPay = grossPay - withholdingAmount - fedTax;
    }

    // Getters

    public String getName ( ) { return this.name; }

    public String getEmployeeId ( ) { return this.employeeId; }

    public int getRegHours ( ) { return this.regHours; }

    public int getOverHours ( ) { return this.overHours; }

    public double getHourlyRate ( ) { return this.hourlyRate; }

    public double getOverRate ( ) { return this.overRate; }

    public double getRegPay ( ) { return this.regPay; }

    public double getOverPay ( ) { return this.overPay; }

    public double getGrossPay ( ) { return this.grossPay; }

    public double getWithholdingAmount ( ) { return this.withholdingAmount; }

    public double getFedTax ( ) { return this.fedTax; }

    public double getNetPay ( ) { return this.netPay; }


    // `Object` overrides
    
    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "PayStub{ " +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | employeeId='" + employeeId + '\'' +
                " | regHours=" + regHours +
                " | overHours=" + overHours +
                " | hourlyRate=" + hourlyRate +
                " | overRate=" + overRate +
                " | regPay=" + regPay +
                " | overPay=" + overPay +
                " | grossPay=" + grossPay +
                " | withholdingAmount=" + withholdingAmount +
                " | fedTax=" + fedTax +
                " | netPay=" + netPay +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Handling data-entry by user.

This code uses the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature in Java 16 and later. A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to transparently and immutably carry data. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
package work.basil.example.paystub;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayStubDataEntry
{

    /**
     * It all starts with the main method.
     *
     * @param args command-line arguments (not used)
     */

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        try(
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        ) {
            PayStubDataEntry app = new PayStubDataEntry();
            PayStubInput input =   app.gatherInput( scanner );
            PayStub payStub = new PayStub(
                    input.name,
                    input.employeeId,
                    input.regHours,
                    input.overhours,
                    input.hourlyRate
            );
         // Report pay stub results.
            System.out.println( "payStub = " + payStub );
        }
        
    }

    public PayStubInput gatherInput ( Scanner keyboard )
    {
        System.out.print( "Enter employee name: " );
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print( "Enter employee identifier (incl. hyphens): " );
        String employeeId = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print( "Enter number of regular hours worked: " );
        int regHours = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter number of overtime hours worked: " );
        int overHours = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter hourly pay rate: " );
        double hourlyRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        PayStubInput input = new PayStubInput(
                Objects.requireNonNull( name ) ,
                Objects.requireNonNull( employeeId ) ,
                Objects.requireNonNull( regHours ) ,
                Objects.requireNonNull( overHours ) ,
                Objects.requireNonNull( hourlyRate )
        );
        return input ;
    }

    record PayStubInput(String name , String employeeId , int regHours , int overhours , double hourlyRate)
    {
    }
}
```

When run. You can see the inaccuracy problem of floating-point numbers in this example run.

```
Enter employee name: Basil
Enter employee identifier (incl. hyphens): AGENT-007
Enter number of regular hours worked: 40
Enter number of overtime hours worked: 12
Enter hourly pay rate: 7
payStub = PayStub{ name='Basil' | employeeId='AGENT-007' | regHours=40 | overHours=12 | hourlyRate=7.0 | overRate=10.5 | regPay=280.0 | overPay=84.0 | grossPay=364.0 | withholdingAmount=36.4 | fedTax=65.52000000000001 | netPay=262.08000000000004 }
```

## Unrelated tips

Classes are best written to focus on a specific job. This is known as the [single-responsibility principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). So a `PayStub` class should focus on knowing how to properly represent a pay stub. It should not know about interacting with a user on the console. So pull that scanner code out to another class.

Social Security Numbers (SSNs) should be kept private as sensitive data. That is why employees are assigned employee numbers when joining a company.

Never use `double`/`Double` or `float`/`Float` for money. These types use floating-point technology to [trade away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution. Accountants prefer accuracy. Instead, either use `BigDecimal` class, or multiply money values to an integer count of pennies or such.

Watch your naming. Your constant `OVERTIME_RATE` is a misnomer. That value is a multiplier by which you determine the actual overtime rate of pay. I imagine a bookkeeper would have a term for this, but I do not know it. If nothing else, call it `OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER`. If you are not comfortable with a name, not sure it is crystal-clear and specific, that is a clue that you may not understand some aspect of the business problem.

You neglected to track the pay period info. Use *java.time* classes for that, probably [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

A [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) object is a resource that should be closed when no longer needed. As a good habit, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically call its [`close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) method. This works because `Scanner` implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).